# Create cross section from 3D Polyline in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, z-value, cross-section

I have a 3d poly line and I want to create a cross section profile using this 3d lines.

What I want to achieve:
I) Create vertices in the 'cross section line' where it intersects with the 3d poly line
II) snap the heights from the 3d poly line into the 'cross section line' vertices

[image]

Comment: @BERA I want to insert a vertices in my cross section line, where it intersect with the 3D Poly line and extract the Z value from the 3D line

Comment: @Babel here is the link: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/gnjio00fpws8i0h/AACHK0UxAKe2l_4MgFETKIBca?dl=0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Result, visulized in 3D map view (red lines), based on your sample data:

[image]

How to achieve this:

1. Split the lines where `3D Line` and `Cross_section_to_generate` intersect. Use `Menu Processing > Toolbox > Split with Lines`. Set the 3D Line as Input and the other line layer as Split layer.
2. Get the Z-value of the start-point of the new lines: these are the cross section points. Use QGIS expressions: `z (start_point ($geometry))`

[image]

If you need the points where lines cross with their z-values on a separate layer, continue as follows:

3. On the layer created in step 2, create a new attribute names `z_value` with Field calculator and this expression: `z (start_point ($geometry))`
4. Run Menu Processing > Toolbox > Geometry by expression, set the layer from step 3 as input, `point` as output geometry type and run it with this expression: `start_point ($geometry)`.

*White points with the interpolated z-value from the blue lines:*
[image]

**Connect the points to lines (cross sections):**

5. Select the points lying on the lines of the layer `Cross_section_to_generate`, using select by expression with this expression: `overlay_nearest ('Cross_section_to_generate', max_distance:=0.01)` (this is to exclude points not lying on cross sections)
6. Use Menu Processing > Toolbox > Points to path with the points as input.

   - Be sure to check to box `Selected features only`.
   - For `Order expression`, use `line_locate_point ( overlay_nearest ('Cross_section_to_generate', $geometry)[0], $geometry)` (the get the line in correct order).
   - For `Path Group expression`, use this expression `overlay_nearest( 'Cross_section_to_generate', $id)[0]`.

   [image]

And here you are with your cross section. The line contains z-values for each vertex. To show the z-value, use `z(point_n($geometry,[no]))` where `[no]` should be replaced with the index of vertex (where 1 is the first vertex).

*Reulst: red lines; z-values for start- end end-points appear in the labels:*
[image]

Comment: what I need is to create vertices on my cross section line where it interests with 3d line and insert z value of the 3d line into cross section vertices

Comment: You didn't state that in your initial question. Please always make as clear as possible what you want to achieve - people here can't know. See updated answer, steps 3 and 4, for that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it really helps me to find the correct tools and expressions. 
I have changed my question now, I hope now it explains well what i really want to do.

Comment: OK, so how to understand that: did my answer solve your problem? Or did it not and in this case: what did not, what do you still miss?

Comment: @ Babel using your step, i can get the results as point shape with z values but what i need is to create a cross section profile from this point as a 'line' shape. 

I use 'point to path' tool to create the cross section profile line using this points, for that i have to create an extra attribute in point shape file and give each point which belong to one  profile an attribute so it can identify each profile section. I did it manually.
if i have 100 profile it is not possible to do this operation manually. so is there any way to give profile number automatically to this points?

Comment: See updated answer

Comment: thanks a lot for the contribution. I didn't work on my own your steps. But it answered my question according to your updated answer 